# Perl Code : Output not displayed properly

Tags: perl

I have a perl code where I access multiple txt files and produce output for them. 
While I run the code, the output lines on the console are overwritten.

```
2015-04-21:12-04-54|getFilesInInputDir|  ********** name : PEPORT **********
PEPORT4-21:12-04-54|readNFormOutputFile|  name :
PEPORT" is : -04-54|readNFormOutputFile| Frequency for name "
```

Please note, that the second and  third line it should have been like

```
2015-04-21:12-04-54|readNFormOutputFile| name : PEPORT
2015-04-21:12-04-54|readNFormOutputFile| Frequency for name "PEPORT"
```

Also, after this the code stops processing my files. The code seems fine. May I know what may be the possible cause for this.

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear what output you want. Surely there should be `is:` in there somewhere? I think you should show your Perl program so that we can help you properly

Answer (score 2):

Seems like CR/LF versus LF issue. Convert your input from MSWin to Linux by running `dos2unix` or `fromdos`, or remove the `"\r"` characters from within the Perl code.

Answer (score 0):

As choroba says, I guess you are reading a file on Linux that has been generated on Windows. The easiest fix is to replace `chomp` with `s/\s+\z//`or `s/\p{cntrl}+\z//`

Or, if trailing spaces are significant, you can use `s/[\r\n]+\z//` or, if you are running version 10 or later of Perl 5, `s/\R\z//`

Comment: Heya, thanks...  I have been using conf file taken from windows and running on Linux. Dint know about this thing. Thank you :) @borodin